# Xamarin.UITest-How to verify element is enabled or disabled

Tags: ui-automation, xamarin.uitest

I am new to xamarin uitest, can any one please help me out how to verify the element is enabled or disabled with an example.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are using Xamarin's Repl then you can use the following

```
app.Query(c => c.Id("ElementID")).FirstOrDefault().Enabled
```

Repl will then return whether the element's enabled property is either true or false

From this, then you can then assign that line to a variable and assert against it

```
var elementEnabled = app.Query(c => c.Id("ElementID")).FirstOrDefault().Enabled;
assert.AreEqual(true, elementEnabled);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand your question, but if what you're asking for is how to check if a toggle button is enabled, then you can go that way :

```
    internal void SetToggle(string id, bool setToggled)
    {
        if (setToggled != IsToggled(id))
            app.Tap(e => e.Property("id").Like(id));
    }

    internal bool IsToggle(string id)
    {
        return app.Query(e => e.Property("id").Like(id).Invoke("isChecked").Value<bool>())[0];

    }
```